# 301 Redirect Get Parameter URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, parameters

I need to 301 redirect an old url that contained a get parameter in the url.

I need to 301 the URL:

```
http://www.website.com/choose?cat=womens
```

to this URL:

```
http://www.website.com/womens
```

I have searched and tried without it working:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cat=womens
RewriteRule ^choose\.php$ /womens [L,R=301]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost correct, just 2 issues:

1. `.php` wasn't there in your original URI after `choose` as per the question
2. You need to add `?` in target to strip original query string

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)cat=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^choose(?:\.php)?$ /%1? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Ah yes didn't notice the php, that was from the example i was basing it on. Thats great thanks. If i have a url that also needs doing but doesn't match the `womens` part in my example how would i do so with your example too? So `http://www.website.com/choose?cat=kids` to `http://www.website.com/baby`

Answer (score -1):

Try these:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=womens$

RewriteRule ^choose$ http://www.website.com/womens? [R=301,L]